# Magento API : XML-RPC Error: Default option value is not defined

Tags: api, magento

I'm integrating Magento with Adempiere ,
Creating/updating product successfully have some attributes in product , i want update values in those attributes

Attribute set Instance

```
{scope=global, code=manufacturer, attribute_id=64, required=0, type=select}
```

My Code:

```
 Product_DATA.put("sku",p.getSku());
 Product_DATA.put("manufacturer",new Object[]{"Zipped"});

 Vector ARGS = new Vector();
 ARGS.add(SESSION_KEY);
 ARGS.add(new String ("catalog_product.create"));
 ARGS.add(new Object[] {p.getType().getType(),4,p.getSku(),Product_DATA});

 this.newRequest(remoteHost, "", SESSION_KEY, "call", ARGS);              
 Object RESULT = (Object) this.sendRequest();
```

Create Code:

```
        HashMap label_DATA = new HashMap<>();
        label_DATA.put("store_id", 0/1); 
        label_DATA.put("value", "bpartner");

        HashMap Vendor_DATA  = new HashMap<>();             
        Vendor_DATA.put("label",new Object[] {label_DATA});
        Vendor_DATA.put("order",0);
        Vendor_DATA.put("is_default",0);        

        Vector ARGS1 = new Vector();
        ARGS1.add(sessionid);
        ARGS1.add(new String ("product_attribute.addOption"));
        ARGS1.add(new Object[] {"manufacturer",new Object[] {Vendor_DATA}});    
        this.newRequest(remoteHost, "", sessionid, "call", ARGS1);

         Object RESULT1 = (Object) this.sendRequest();
```

**Error while create :**

```
XML-RPC Error: Default option value is not defined
```

I want to create / update this "manufacturer" column in Product window , please anyone help to resolve this

Comment: Can you describe the problem with more details? Are you trying to create a magento API endpoint that will allow you to call it from outside and update a specific value for a product/category?

Comment: I have added manufacturer(asi) column in product window , i need to update this column from adempiere to magento in webservices (SOAP API)